# How to generate random values using SQL queries?

Tags: sql

I need to generate a lot of tuples in my database in order to use it to test my logic before deploying an application.

The database has 2 tables, here is the schema for the first table (sorry it's in french):

```sql
CREATE TABLE utilisateurs (
  id_utilisateur INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  prenom VARCHAR(255),
  nom VARCHAR(255),
  date_de_naissance DATE,
  email VARCHAR(255),
  mot_de_passe VARCHAR(255),
  maladie_chronique VARCHAR(255),
  latitude DECIMAL(9, 6),
  longitude DECIMAL(9, 6)
);
```

And here is the schema of the second table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE utilisateurs_malade (
    id_report INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_utilisateur INT,
    dernirement_malade DATE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_utilisateur FOREIGN KEY (id_utilisateur) REFERENCES utilisateurs(id_utilisateur)
);
```

I need to generate 500 or more tuples for the first table with random values (random but logical values, I don't want the date_de_naissance which must be the date of birth in 500-05-02 for example) and 300 or more tuples for the second table with random values aswell (random but logical values aswell, for example: the id_utilisateur must refer to the first table, I also want the latitude and longitude to be in Algeria, in other words

Latitude:

Minimum: 18.969168
Maximum: 37.101043

Longitude:

Minimum: -8.673947
Maximum: 11.999273

How can do this without manually typing down more than 800 queries ?

Comment: mysql and sql server are different databases with different syntax. which one do you want, according to your code it looks more like mysql

Comment: What kind of database do you use? Every database has own syntax for random. For example for postgres you can use: random() * 9 + 1 -> numbers between 1&10

Comment: I didn't decide yet which database I'm gonna use but it's probably sql server @siggemannen

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a method, I've shared an example below that generates 500 random tuples for the 'utilisateurs' table and 300 random tuples for the 'utilisateurs_malade' table.

```
--generate random data for utilisateurs table
INSERT INTO utilisateurs (prenom, nom, date_de_naissance, email, mot_de_passe, maladie_chronique, latitude, longitude)
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 5), -- prenom
    SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 5), -- nom
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 15000) DAY), -- date_de_naissance
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 5), '.', SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 5), '@example.com'), -- email
    'password123', -- mot_de_passe
    IF(RAND() < 0.5, 'diabetes', IF(RAND() < 0.5, 'hypertension', IF(RAND() < 0.5, 'asthma', 'none'))), -- maladie_chronique
    RAND() * (37.101043 - 18.969168) + 18.969168, -- latitude
    RAND() * (11.999273 - (-8.673947)) + (-8.673947) -- longitude
FROM 
    (SELECT @num:=0) AS n
WHERE 
    @num < 500 -- assuming you want to generate 500 tuples

-- generate random data for utilisateurs_malade table
INSERT INTO utilisateurs_malade (id_utilisateur, dernièrement_malade)
SELECT 
    FLOOR(RAND() * 500) + 1, -- id_utilisateur
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 30) DAY) -- dernièrement_malade
FROM 
    (SELECT @num:=0) AS n
WHERE 
    @num < 300 -- assuming you want to generate 300 tuples
```

Please also note that it is assumed that at least 500 records are already present in the utilisateurs table (so that the randomly generated id_utilisateur in the utilisateurs_malade table is referred to existing records). Also, the RAND() function generates a random floating-point number between 0 and 1, so we can use it to generate random values within a range.

Comment: Is this for MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: RAND() doesn't randomize per row though, so this will generate same values. You gotta use a view hack to get random values, although maybe it does in MYSQL :)

Comment: does it work for sqlite3 ?